# Emacs: How to debug hooks?

Tags: emacs

I'm getting an error in my Emacs config and I believe it's occurring on a hook function, but I don't know how to get a backtrace or see where the error is since I can't get the debugger to enter a hook function. How can I debug hook functions?

Comment: What functions are attached to the hook?  `M-x describe-variable RET michael-dickens-hook RET`.  What major mode are you using  and what are you doing, and what specifically is the error message and/or problem?  Enable debugging with `(setq debug-on-error t)` to see more helpful messages regarding a potential problem.  What minor modes are active in the buffer when the problem occurs -- `M-x describe-mode RET`   Check the `*Messages*` buffer for error messages and also the `*Backtrace*` buffer that will appear when `debug-on-error` is enabled.

Comment: @lawlist: Part of the problem is I have no idea which hook is causing the error. When I invoke (org-mode) in certain buffers, on exit it raises the error "Abort: end-of-buffer". This only happens in some buffers and it only happens when the function exits which is what makes me think it's happening in a hook. The backtrace just says it's coming from the invocation of (org-mode) but it's actually not happening until after (org-mode) exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like you know what command causes the hook to be run (`org-mode`) but not which hook is the culprit.  I would start by using [this function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19582/8647) to tell you which hooks to look at.  (Well, actually, I'd start by looking at `org-mode-hook`, but I'm going to assume you already thought of that.)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use this to find a hook I had added that was causing an error.